# List of elements in a User Control or a Grid

Tags: c#, silverlight

Hello i have an user control and i need all the textbox , buttons, etc from this user control
This there a way that i have all this elements?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

you can use the [VisualTreeHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to achieve this.

There's an article [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kmahone/archive/2009/03/29/visualtreehelper.aspx) that offers the following extension method to help:

```
public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> GetVisuals(this DependencyObject root)
{
    int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);
        yield return child;
        foreach (var descendants in child.GetVisuals())
        {
            yield return descendants;
        }
    }
}
```

You can then do the following:

```
foreach (var control in LayoutRoot.GetVisuals().OfType<Control>())
{
    //handle control of type <Control>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

BrokenGlass's method works for sure, but it's a bit obtuse. Here is a simplified way of doing it:

When you create a control in VisualStudio or Blend, generally you're going to get a UserControl with a grid inside.

```
<UserControl x:Class="RHooligan"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid x:Name="RootElement>

</Grid>
```

Assuming your UserControl's Root element is a container control (Grid,StackPanel,Canvas, etc) and you've named it **RootElement**, you can do this to iterate through it's children.

```
      foreach(FrameworkElement element in RootElement.Children)
  {
    //do something with element
    //////////////////////////
  }
```